# How to click on item in an unsigned list using Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I have a web page that has buttons 
  First, Prev, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, Next, Last

I want to auto click "Next" (and others) but I cannot find the correct way to do this from an unsigned list.

I can navigate to the specific item in the list. However, I cannot perform a .click() on that item without returning an error.

This is the section of the html code

```
<nav>
    <input type="hidden" id="page" name="page" value="2">
    <input type="hidden" id="resetPage" name="resetPage" value="">
    <input type="hidden" id="info_firstPage" value="/info#PCB">
    <ul id="info_pageclass" class="pageclass">
        <li class="disabled" style="pointer-events: none;"><a href="/info#PCB"><span>First</span></a></li>,
        <li class="disabled" style="pointer-events: none;"><a href="/info/page0#PCB" rel="prev"><span>Prev</span></a></li>,
        <li class="hidden-xs" style="pointer-events: none;"><a href="/info" style="background: #41ace2 !important; color: #fff !important;">1</a></li>,
        <li class="hidden-xs"><a href="/info/page2#PCB">2</a></li>,
        <li class="hidden-xs"><a href="/info/page3#PCB">3</a></li>,
        <li class="hidden-xs"><a href="/info/page4#PCB">4</a></li>,
        <li class="hidden-xs"><a href="/info/page5#PCB">5</a></li>,
        <li><a href="/info/page2#PCB" rel="next"><span>Next</span></a></li>,
        <li><a href="/info/page9#PCB"><span>Last</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

This is the python code stepping thru' with the IDE

```
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, features='html.parser')
>>> next = soup.find("ul", attrs={"id":"info_pageclass"}).find_all("li")[7]
>>> print(next)
<li>
<a href="/info/page2#PCB" rel="next">
<span>Next</span>
</a>
</li>
```

These statements all return the same error as shown (once)

```
>>> next.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
>>> next.click()
>>> next.a.click()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Comment: share your website link.

Comment: You click using bs4 element; Use [this](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To `click()` on the element with text as **Next** you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "ul.pageclass#info_pageclass li>a[rel='next']>span"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//ul[@class='pageclass' and @id='info_pageclass']//li/a[@rel='next']/span[text()='Next']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Thankyou :) 
Both the CSS and XPATH lines worked.

I presume the wait is necessary for the focus to move to the button before clicking it?

Comment: @Cluso99 Yes, it is, as per best practices always use WebDriverWait for the _element to be clickable_ before invoking `click()`

Answer (score 0):

Use `Selenium` and `BeautifulSoup`. Use `infinite while loop` and search for next button element.However this will break when there is no next button element present on the page.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'Url here'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"html.parser")

#While loop search for the `Next` button on the page if not found jumps out from the loop.
while True:
    #Some code of your operation

    if len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//ul[@id="info_pageclass"]//li/a/span[contains(.,"Next")]'))>0:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//ul[@id="info_pageclass"]//li/a/span[contains(.,"Next")]').click()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"html.parser")
    else:
        break
```